# PHP loop through arrays inside array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Im trying to loop through an array that is made from a couple of arrays that each has 2 properties and another array with diffrent number of properties.
im trying to output all the properties of the last array using foreach.

```
 $gallery = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'HaPartizanim',
        'file' => './assets/cubes/HaPartizanim.png',
        $slides => array(
            'slide1' => './assets/pop-up/HaPartizanim-1.png',
            'slide2' => './assets/pop-up/HaPartizanim-2.png',
            'slide3' => './assets/pop-up/HaPartizanim-3.png',
            'slide4' => './assets/pop-up/HaPartizanim-4.png'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Toro House',
        'file' => './assets/cubes/Toro_House.png',
        $slides => array(
            'slide1' => './assets/pop-up/Toro_House-1.png',
            'slide2' => './assets/pop-up/Toro_House-2.png',
            'slide3' => './assets/pop-up/Toro_House-3.png'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'HaAgana',
        'file' => './assets/cubes/HaAgana.png',
        $slides => array(
            'slide1' => './assets/pop-up/HaAgana-1.png',
            'slide2' => './assets/pop-up/HaAgana-2.png',
            'slide3' => './assets/pop-up/HaAgana-3.png',
            'slide4' => './assets/pop-up/HaAgana-4.png'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Har HaCarmel',
        'file' => './assets/cubes/Har_HaCarmel.png',
        $slides => array(
            'slide1' => './assets/pop-up/Har_HaKarmel-1.png',
            'slide2' => './assets/pop-up/Har_HaKarmel-2.png',
            'slide3' => './assets/pop-up/Har_HaKarmel-3.png',
            'slide4' => './assets/pop-up/Har_HaKarmel-4.png',
        )
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Kohvei Itzhak',
        'file' => './assets/cubes/Kohvei_Itzhak.png',
        $slides => array(
            'slide1' => './assets/pop-up/Kohvei_Itzhak-1.png',
            'slide2' => './assets/pop-up/Kohvei_Itzhak-2.png'
        )
    )
);
```

what i have so far and is not working is

```
foreach($gallery as $key => $slides){
  foreach($slides as $key => $slide){
            $slide1 = $slide['slide1'];
            $slide2 = $slide['slide2'];
    echo $slide1, $slide2 . "<br/>";
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: You have a typo. Use `.` to concatenate $slide1 and $slide2, not comma `,`

Comment: `$slides => array(` is invalid

Comment: What is the desired output? You want all "slideX" data in a list? Order by "title"? And as GrumpyCrouton mentionned it : you can't have var `$slides` inside your php array, it should be `slides => array(...)` no?

Comment: I want all the slides. a div for each slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `$slides => array(` is invalid syntax. I will assume you actually meant `'slides' => array(` - if that's true, the following code will list all of the properties from each array using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
foreach($gallery as $key => $slides){
    echo implode(', ', $slides['slides']) . "<br>";
}
```

If you want to do additional processing for each slide, loop through like this:

```
foreach($gallery as $key => $slides){
    foreach($slides['slides'] as $sub_key => $slide) {
        echo "<div>Key: $sub_key<br>Slide: $slide</div>";
    }
}
```